# URL ZOOM PARAMETER for exporting sheet to pdf

Tags: url, google-apps-script, google-sheets, export-to-pdf

Another question on URL parameters... sorry. Actually, I've been searching a lot about how to solve this, here and pretty much everywhere else, and I found absolutely nothing. Zero!

Really appreciate if someone can give me a hand. Here's the thing, I'm exporting a google sheet to pdf with the following URL code.

```
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export"+
                                                        "?format=pdf&"+
                                                        "size=7&"+
                                                        "portrait=false&"+
                                                        // "zoom_scale=130&"+
                                                        "top_margin=0.00&"+
                                                        "bottom_margin=0.00&"+
                                                        "left_margin=0.00&"+
                                                        "right_margin=0.00&"+
                                                        "horizontal_alignment=LEFT&"+
                                                        "vertical_alignment=TOP";
                                                        //"gridlines=false&";
                                                        //"printtitle=false&"+
                                                        //"sheetnames=false&"+
                                                        //"pagenum=UNDEFINED&"+
                                                        //"attachment=false";
```

It works just fine, but my problem is that I'd like to add a 130% zoom. Just to save you the trouble, I know and tried the 'scale' parameter, but that's not what I'm looking for. It might help the hero who accepts to save me from this hell :-) to know that I'm exporting a graphic and that the 'scale' parameter doesn't have any effect on the pdf. Meaning: no matter which value I choose for the 'scale' parameter, the graphic is exported with the same exact size in the A4 pdf.

I tried to export it manually to pdf with that 130% zoom I need using the printing dialog box, which I'm guessing sets exactly the same parameters we work with here, so I believe it should be possible to use the same parameter in an URL.

What I'm missing is how to include it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hello Ricardo! Could you please share the Sheet / a picture of the Sheet in question and describe what should your exported PDF file look like? Thank you!!

Comment: Hello player0. Thanks for your help. Here's the link to the spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nkwwGwEvHELo9IcZ6nV1whyVNZOhdTsJfVIZ7D3r6Mg/edit?usp=drivesdk.  What I want is the sheet "Resultado" (um Portuguese, sorry) to be exported to a full page pdf. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

By tracking down the requests that Sheets is internally doing (and checking the link below), I have come up to the following solution:

```js
function encodeDate(yy, mm, dd, hh, ii, ss) {
    var days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    if (((yy % 4) == 0) && (((yy % 100) != 0) || ((yy % 400) == 0))) days[1] = 29;
    for (var i = 0; i < mm; i++) dd += days[i];
    yy--;
    return ((((yy * 365 + ((yy - (yy % 4)) / 4) - ((yy - (yy % 100)) / 100) + ((yy - (yy % 400)) / 400) + dd - 693594) * 24 + hh) * 60 + ii) * 60 + ss) / 86400.0;
}

function exportPDF(ssID, source, options, format) {
    var dt = new Date();
    var d = encodeDate(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate(), dt.getHours(), dt.getMinutes(), dt.getSeconds());
    var pc = [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0,
        source,
        10000000, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
        d,
        null, null,
        options,
        format,
        null, 0, null, 0
    ];
    var js = " \
<script> \
window.open('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ssID + "/pdf?id=" + ssID + "&a=true&pc=" + JSON.stringify(pc) + "&gf=[]'); \
google.script.host.close(); \
</script> \
";

    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(js)
        .setHeight(10)
        .setWidth(100);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Save To PDF");
}

function myExportPDF() {
    var as = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = as.getSheetByName('Resultado');
    exportPDF(as.getId(), // Spreadsheet ID
        [
            [sheet.getSheetId().toString()] // Sheet ID
        ],
        [
            0, // Do not show notes
            null,
            1, // Show grid lines
            0, // Do not show page numbers
            0, // Do not show book title
            0, // Do not show sheet title
            0, // Do not show date
            0, // Do not show time
            1, // Repeat pinned rows
            1, // Repeat pinned columns
            1, // Page order down then up
            2,
            null,
            [
                null,
                null,
                ["kocheam.com"]
            ],
            1, // Left Alignment
            2 // Top Alignment
        ],
        [
            "A4", // A4 sheet format
            0, // Page Orientation Vertical
            5, // Align to height
            1.3, // Zoom
            [
                0, // Top margin 0.75 inch
                0, // Bottom margin 0.75 inch
                0, // Left margin 0.7 inch
                0 // Right margin 0.7 inch
            ]
        ]
    );
}
```

This code will download your "Resultado" Sheet as PDF with the format you expect. Furthermore, you can add this code to your menu by changing the onOpen function as follows:

```js
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.createMenu('X Menu')
    .addItem('Criar gráficos', 'resultAutomation')
    .addSeparator()
    .addItem('Print graph', 'myExportPDF') // NEW
    .addToUi();
```

#### Reference

- [Export Google Sheets to PDF](https://kandiral.ru/googlescript/eksport_tablic_google_sheets_v_pdf_fajl.html)