# Google Script: Setting custom scale, when exporting to PDF

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have written script to export my Google spreadsheet to a PDF, but the scale is wrong. I need to set a custom scale of 70%, but as far as I can tell, my options regarding scale customisation are:

- 1 = Normal 100%,
- 2 = Fit to width,
- 3 = Fit to height and
- 4 = Fit to Page.

Below is some redacted script.

```
var exporturl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' +
'xxxxxx' +  //file ID
  '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' +
    '&size=A4' +
      '&portrait=true' +
        '&scale=3' + // My question refers to this line
          '&top_margin=0.50' +            
            '&bottom_margin=0.50' +         
              '&left_margin=0.50' +        
                '&right_margin=0.50' +     
                  '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' +
                    '&pagenum=false' +
                      '&gridlines=true' +
                        '&fzr=FALSE' +
                          '&gid=' +
                            'yyyyyyy'; //the sheet's Id
```

Is it possible to set a custom scale or am I bound to the 4 options? Also, if anyone can suggest a workaround, I'd apprecite it.

Comment: I don't think there is a parameter to set a custom scale. But maybe [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58840616) could work for you?